# How do I get the mx records for a domain from *nix command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, dns

What is the best way to lookup MX records for a domain from the command line?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Here are 4 options, in order from least to most verbose:

```
dig +short -t mx mydomain.com
host -t mx mydomain.com
nslookup -q=mx mydomain.com
dig -t mx mydomain.com
```

(Thanks to bortzmeyer for suggesting `dig +short`.)

The difference is largely a matter of personal preference and what your goal is. I tend to use `host`, but if you want full details about exactly what you're getting back from the server (e.g. because you're troubleshooting DNS), `dig` is the way to go. On the third hand, if you're doing this in a script, the output from `dig +short` is going to be easiest to parse.

Comment: No, the option the LEAST verbose is `dig +short MX mydomain.com`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
nslookup -q=mx mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 8):

`dig -t mx mydomain.com` will work as well.